# Ghost Script does not generate images when integrated with C#

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf, ghostscript

I am into a weird problem. The below command on command line works fine and generates images.

```
C:\Program Files\gs\gs8.54\bin>gswin32c.exe -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r150 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dMaxStripSize=8192 -sOutputFile=image_%d.png 828787-1.pdf
```

But when i try to use the same command in .Net application it neither complains nor generates images.

```
    Dim process As Process
    Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo

    SetPath()'Setting path for Ghost script folder.
    info.FileName = "gswin32c.exe"

    Dim outputFileName As String = String.Format("{0}\Image_%d.png", destFilePath)

    info.Arguments = "-dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r150 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dMaxStrip Size=8192 -sOutputFile=""" + outputFileName + """"
    info.Arguments += " """ + sourceFile + """"

    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    process = process.Start(info)
    process.WaitForExit()
```

The source and destination file paths are UNC paths and are reachable. If I use them on command prompt, they work fine.
Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Are no errors thrown? Is it an application or a website?  Without any additional information, my first guess would be - that when it works in the command prompt - that you might have some security settings for your .NET application so it's not running under a user context that has the needed rights to write in the folders.

Comment: No :(, no errors are shown, at least no catch statement is being hit. The user context are same in both the cases. The application is WinForm.

Comment: **Finally figured out.**
It was due to unnecessary space in "-dMaxStripSize=8192", which was failing in  background. 

I used  gswin32.exe instead of gswin32c.exe which shows the verbose output of the command executed. This actually told that it is failing to find file path (misleading though but gave an opportunity to look back to the command).

Thanks for your help Allan. Appreciate your quick turn around.